# How can I generate terrain under road?

Tags: modifiers, vertex-groups

I've this project: 
[image]

I'm beginner so I don't know how can I do that, I want to edit surface to align with the road.
Like that:
[image]

Am I able to do that without editing every vertex?

Comment: .. Much easier, (as in real life,)  to _start_ with the landscape, and conform (shrinkwrap) the road to it, than the other way around. The landscape contains full information about where the road should go.. the road can't determine the shape of the landscape where it isn't there..

Comment: @Jarosław Chrobak Upload your mix file, I'll show you the simple way by creating the example with your terrain and your highway, use this link tu up your blend and follow the instructions [Upload Blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: The solution (if there is) could be really dependent on your actual models (both roads and terrain) and what you aim to do (in particular the wanted polycount).